# How to $watch if checbox is checked or uncheck in ng-repeat table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currenty have a watch function but it only watch when I click on the select all checkbox. on any individual row when I click the check box the watch function doesn't activates.

Script side code:

```
$scope.$watch("checkboxes.checked", function(bool) {
}
```

HTML code:

```
<table ng-table="testTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in $data">
            <td data-title="Selection">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.items[data.id]"/>
        </td>
            <td data-title="data"> 
                {{data.name}} 
            < /td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I watch every individual row's checkbox?
Thanks.

Comment: you should use `ng-change` in the input

Comment: Thanks, I could use ng-click too. But I don't want to do it that way, i'm sure there's a way to watch each individual checkbox,

Comment: You know ng-change will look for every changes of every checkboxes right ? and make a custom action with a function

Comment: I knew about ng-change just wondering how do I use the $watch function to watch changes in any checkboxes. Anyway thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use ngchange as watching a whole collection of data can be heavy lifting.

```
<table ng-table="testTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in $data">
            <td data-title="Selection">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.items[data.id]" ng-change="doSomething(data.id)"/>
        </td>
            <td data-title="data"> 
                {{data.name}} 
            < /td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in your controller,

```
$scope.doSomething = function(dataId) {
    console.log('checkbox' + data.id + ' status');
    console.log(checkboxes.items[data.id]);
}
```

you can improvise from there.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about ng-change just wondering how do I use the $watch function to watch changes in any checkboxes. Anyway your answer is considered a solution to my question, so i'll tick it as an answer.

Comment: you can use watch collection.  $watchCollection('checkboxes.items')